# Facebook API {"error":{"message":"(#100) No matching user found","type":"OAuthException" Checkbox Plugin

Tags: facebook, api, checkbox, plugins, messenger

I am trying to use the feature of the checkbox plugin. I manage to make the checkbox rendered. A few days ago, I managed to send some basic text 'Hello World' to the user. But now I'm not able to send anything thing. Whenever I tried to send to the user I get this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) No matching user found","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018001,"fbtrace_id":"HCZPBkofiz9"}}
```

I even try to cURL using, but no success, still the same error.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient": {
      "user_ref":"<UNIQUE_REF_PARAM>"
  }, 
  "message": {
      "text":"hello, world!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

What I've done are:

1. Uninstalled app from the page.
2. Select the page again and generate new PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN.
3. Subscribe to messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins webhooks to the page.
4. Set the new token in .env.
5. Save up the new user_ref through checkbox plugin.
6. Try cURL by using the new user_ref, no luck.

I am able to send with recipient senderID but not user_ref for checkbox plugin.

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: I don’t think you’re supposed to use the user_ref to send a message to the user more than once. The user has to respond to your initial message first, upon which you will receive a callback that now includes a sender id, and you have to use that one for further messaging. See “7. Handle the user response” in the checkbox plugin documentation.

Comment: Yes, I can by using the user_ref. Also yes, I'm only want to send to the user only once then I will delete the user_ref forever from database. It's on number "6. Send a message with user_ref" on the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin/#implementation). If the send message success then I can proceed with 7. Handle the user response.

Comment: Am I missing any permission?

Comment: Error message doesn’t sound like it’s a permission issue. Can you try with a different user?

Comment: I just tried what you said, but still no avail. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Just like what I explain, I do succeed send message using the user_ref before. Until yesterday, I accidentally generate new token for the page. Thus, I copied the new token and set it. Create new user_ref, since then I'm getting this error. Hope this can give you an idea.

Comment: Also this error  `"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (User)"` when I'm try to `GET -> 3.1 -> me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>` through the Graph API Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Turn out I'm confuse with all the access token because they all nearly the same BUT it's actually not. To get the right access token I use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?classic=0).

Steps:

On the Access Token section:

1. Facebook App, I select my app that I'm using for my project.
2. User or Page, I change it to my Page to get the Page Access Tokens. It will generate the Page Access Token automatically.
3. I select the permission that I need. For my project, manage_pages and pages_messaging are crucial.

**Note**: If you click Get Access Token it will generate a new one and it is actually not the same.

After select the permission, to test the generated Access token I do the following steps:

On the Graph API Explorer:

1. Change the method from GET to POST. This will let you write in Params and JSON.
2. From cURL example in [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin/) documentation on number 6. Copy the JSON part only and put in JSON field.
3. Change the `<UNIQUE_REF_PARAM>` to the one that I have saved in db like this:

   ```
   {
       "recipient": {
           "user_ref": "xplynagfqasoiuqnwyepnyiqe"
       },
       "message": {
           "text": "hello, world!"
       }
   }
   ```
4. Since the cURL example send to

   `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>`.

So I change the submit to `POST->/v3.1->/me/messages`

5. Submit the POST.

On success, the Send API will respond with a message_id:

```
{
    "message_id": "mid.1456970487936:c34767dfe57ee6e339"
}
```

And that mean you can use the generated Access Token on right side as your PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN.